# why does border fix height issue

Tags: css

I have this setup:

```
//html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <svg viewBox="-10 -10 920 620">…</svg>
  </div>
</div>


//css
.wrap {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  /* 
   * the below fixes the issue
   * why?
   *
   */
  border: 1px #00ff00 solid;

}

.inner {
  margin: -10px -10px;  
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

So the `.inner` creates negative margin to enlarge the `<svg>` within for 20px on width and height. So in case the viewport is wide enough, lets say 1000px, I expect the `.wrap` to be 900 x 600 px in size and the svg to be 920 x 620 px.

But `.wrap` appears to be 900 x 620 px, so too high. Adding `border: 1px #00ff00 solid;` to the `.wrap` element fixes that. Why?